# Best practice when using a Rails app to overwrite a file that the app relies on

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails app that reads from a .yml file each time that it performs a search.  (This is a full text search app.)  The .yml file tells the app which url it should be making search requests to because different version of the search index reside on different servers, and I occasionally switch between indexes.

I have an admin section of the app that allows me to rewrite the aforementioned .yml file so that I can add new search urls or remove unneeded ones.  While I could manually edit the file on the server, I would prefer to be able to also edit it in my site admin section so that when I don't have access to the server, I can still make any necessary changes.

What is the best practice for making edits to a file that is actually used by my app?  (I guess this could also apply to, say, an app that had the ability to rewrite one of its own helper files, post-deployment.)

Is it a problem that I could be in the process of rewriting this file while another user connecting to my site wants to perform a search?  Could I make their search fail if I'm in the middle of a write operation?  Should I initially write my new .yml file to a temp file and only later replace the original .yml file?  I know that a write operation is pretty fast, but I just wanted to see what others thought.

**UPDATE:** Thanks for the replies everyone!  Although I see that I'd be better off using some sort of caching rather than reading the file on each request, it helped to find out what the best way to actually do the file rewrite is, given that I'm specifically looking to re-read it each time in this specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use a file for this then the safe process looks like this:

1. Write the new content to a temporary file of some sort.
2. Use [`File.rename`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-rename) to atomically replace the old file with the new one.

If you don't use separate files, you can easily end up with a half-written broken file when the inevitable problems occur. The `File.rename` class method is just a wrapper for the [`rename(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html) system call and that's guaranteed to be atomic (i.e. it either fully succeeds or fully fails, it won't leave you in an inconsistent in-between state).

If you want to replace `/some/path/f.yml` then you'd do something like this:

```
begin
  # Write your new stuff to /some/path/f.yml.tmp here
  File.rename('/some/path/f.yml.tmp', '/some/path/f.yml')
rescue SystemCallError => e
  # Log an error, complain loudly, fall over and cry, ...
end
```

As others have said, a file really isn't the best way to deal with this and if you have multiple servers, using a file will fail when the servers become out of sync. You'd be better off using a database that several servers can access, then you could:

1. Cache the value in each web server process.
2. Blindly refresh it every 10 minutes (or whatever works).
3. Refresh the cached value if connecting to the remote server fails (with extra error checking to avoid refresh/connect/fail loops).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this via overwriting files, use the filesystem's locking features to block other threads from accessing your configuration file while it's being written. Maybe check out something like [this](http://disjointthoughts.com/2007/01/15/file-locking-in-ruby-using-flock/).

I'd strongly recommend not using files for configuration that needs to be changed without re-deploying the app though. First, you're now requiring that a file be read every time someone does a search. Second, for security reasons it's generally a bad idea to allow your web application write access to its own code.  I would store these search index URLs in the database or a memcached key.

**edit:** As @bioneuralnet points out, it's important to decide whether you need real-time configuration updates or just eventual syncing.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let me say that reading that file on every request is a performance killer. Don't do it! If you really really need to keep that data in a .yml file, then you need to cache it and reload only after it changes (based on the file's timestamp.)

But don't check the timestamp every on every request - that's almost as bad. Check it on a request if it's been n minutes since the last check. Probably in a `before_filter` somewhere. And if you're running in threaded mode (most people aren't), be careful that you're using a Mutex or something.